# R: Match a dataframe with 3 others, and create a column

Tags: r, merge, match

I have a big data frame (df) with a variable id, and 3 other data (df1, df2, df3) frames that have some values of this id. So like the big dataframe has id 1:100, df1 might have 1,2,4,11 etc.

What i need to do is add a column to the big dataframe so that it says from which of the smaller dataframes the data came from.

```
df$new[df$id %in% df1$id] <- 1
df$new[df$id %in% df2$id] <- 2
df$new[df$id %in% df3$id] <- 3

df$new<- factor(df$new, labels = c('a', 'b', 'c'))
```

This is my solution but i don't really like it. Any other ideas?

Comment: Is this a problem of programming? IMO it is a matter of taste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a nested `ifelse`

```
with(df, ifelse(id %in% df1$id, 'a',
         ifelse(id %in% df2$id, 'b',
         ifelse(id %in% df3$id, 'c', id)))
```